# How can I guarantee that a boolean is true for only one row with a particular ForeignKey in Django?

Tags: python, database, django, foreign-keys, race-condition

Imagine something like this:

```py
class User(models.Model):
     name = CharField(max_length=80)

class TelephoneNumber(models.Model):
     phone_number = CharField(max_length=10)
     user = ForeignKey(User)
     is_default_number = BooleanField
```

Suppose I want to guarantee that there is only one default phone number per user. We can have as many as we want that have `is_default_number == False`, but for each `user` there should be only *one* that has `is_default_number == True`.

Is there any way to enforce this at the database level through Django? I know one simple solution in pure Python is this:

```py
class TelephoneNumber(models.Model):
    phone_number = CharField(max_length=10)
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    is_default_number = BooleanField

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         other_defaults_same_user = TelephoneNumber.objects.filter(
              user=self.user,
              is_default_number=True
         ).exclude(
              pk=self.pk
         )

         if self.is_default_number and other_defaults_same_user.exists():
              raise ValidationError("Can't have two phone numbers as default"
                                    " for one user.")

         super(TelephoneNumber, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But this is pretty vulnerable to a race condition bug, and I don't like how we have to do an extra read every time we save (that extra read is probably necessary at some point, though). Is there any way to accomplish this in Django? If we have to make the answer database-dependent, I'd be interested to see the answers, but obviously a backend-independent one would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just make default_phone_number a foreign key on the user model?

Answer (score 0):

Use model field validation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects.

```
if self.is_default_number and TelephoneNumber.objects.filter(user=self.user, is_default_number=True).exclude(id=self.id).exists():
#throw ValidationError
```

I don't think you can avoid the extra read though.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as the solution posted in the question? Since model field validation needs to happen inside the `save` method, it seems that it's still vulnerable to race conditions.

Comment: No. Best practice is to avoid overriding the save button as much as possible. That's why model validation and signals were created.